# Is there any way to avoid logback.xml configuration instead of can i annotate a java class with @Configuaration?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, logback, slf4j

can I use java class and @Configuration annotation for creating logger file ? rather than using logback.xml configuration ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no `@Configuration` annotation that is handled by Logback. However, you can implement [`Configurator`](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/spi/Configurator.java) interface as a [service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html). As of 1.3.0-beta1, it will be called before the `DefaultJoranConfigurator`.